# kaminari ajax pagination works locally, not on heroku production

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku, kaminari

i am trying to get ajax pagination to work with Kaminari in my production environment on Heroku. At present running the code locally in dev mode it all seems to work. i cant seem to find what would be causing it to work locally, but not in production

console output

```
Started GET "/events/page/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-02 21:48:33 +1100
Processing by EventsController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"event_page"=>"2"}
```

events_controller

```
def index
    @events = Event.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.haml
      format.json
      format.js
    end
  end
```

index.js.haml

```
$('#events').html('#{escape_javascript render('events_list')}');
$('#events_page').html('#{escape_javascript render('paginator')}');
$('#event_counter').html('(#{pluralize(@events.count, 'event')})');
```

index.html.haml

```
%section.section
    %p.title= link_to 'List View', '#events'
    .content{'data-slug'=>'events'}
      %p#events= render 'events/events_list'
      = render 'events/paginator'
```

heroku logs

```
2013-04-02T10:29:39+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/events/page/2" for 203.206.108.64 at 
2013-04-02 10:29:38 +0000
2013-04-02T10:29:39+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-02T10:29:39+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-02T10:29:39+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/events/page/2 host=www.*****.com.au fwd="203.206.108.64" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=1062ms status=304 bytes=0
```

Comment: in what way is it not working? Is it just a styling issue or are you getting an exception? Which rails version are you on?

Comment: the content isnt being reissued when i click to change page `ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]` `Rails 3.2.3`

Comment: those versions are local, not sure what heroku is using

Comment: you should first check error in firebug. That will help.

Comment: anyone else had an issue like this?

Comment: Did you ever find solution for this?  I'm having the same issue even in newer versions.